# django ModelChoiceField, to_field_name

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

When I compile my code, this error message is returned:

> 'ModelChoiceField' object has no attribute 'to_field_name'

ModelChoiceFiled is in the 'school_code' field.

I already type to_field_name.

```
class UserRegister(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        mstSchool = MstSchool.objects.filter(use_yn__exact="Y").order_by("code")
        
        model = MstUser
        fields = [ 'name', 'id', 'password', 'school_code']
        widgets = {
            'id' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder' : 'User ID', 'class':'form-control'}),
            'password' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder' : 'password', 'class':'form-control school-password', 'type':'password'}),
            'name' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder' : 'name', 'class':'form-control school-name'}),
            'school_code' : forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=MstSchool.objects.filter(use_yn__exact="Y").order_by("code"), empty_label="(Nothing)", to_field_name="school_code")
        }
```

> 'ModelChoiceField' object has no attribute 'to_field_name'

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing fields and widgets. A `ModelChoiceField` is *not* a widget, but a form field:

```
class UserRegister(forms.ModelForm):

    school_code = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=MstSchool.objects.filter(use_yn__exact="Y").order_by("code"), empty_label="(Nothing)")

    class Meta:
        model = MstUser
        fields = [ 'name', 'id', 'password', 'school_code']
        widgets = {
            'id' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder' : 'User ID', 'class':'form-control'}),
            'password' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder' : 'password', 'class':'form-control school-password', 'type':'password'}),
            'name' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder' : 'name', 'class':'form-control school-name'}),
        }
```

Please do *not* set the `id` and the `password` through the `ModelForm`. Passwords should be hashed, and usually the [**`set_password`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/) is used for that.